# Preventing HTML Attribute Wrapping Using Formatting

Tags: html, reactjs, format, prettier

I'm having an issue with code formatting, where the attributes of HTML tags are being wrapped to new lines when I format the code. This makes it difficult to read HTML tags. Is there a way to prevent them from being wrapped after formatting?

[image: Ex: the attributes of div are being wrapped]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Select Language Mode to JSX in status bar

Enable Format on save in Editor settings

Use https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode

Comment: 've done what you told me, but it still isn't working